# Can I detect events in commerical software and display message?

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, algorithm, ipc

I'm new to programming and would like to create a program that detects an event in a store bought software and displays a message box that requires the user to click "OK" in order to continue. The commercial program is run in Windows XP and I need it to detect when someone clicks a specific menu option. What programming language would be best and is this possible if I don't have access to the source code of the commercial program? It also might work if the program detects specific words that appear on the screen since after clicking the menu option in the commercial program certain unique text appears.

Comment: Check whether you got access to any API exposed by the programme which will trigger an event

Comment: I'm not sure it's a program I use at work so I don't have much access

Answer (score 1):

t1085ok,

The answer is yes.

I suggest Autohotkey (AHK). It is beginner-level, yet provides powerful functions to do things like you want to do.

You can download it for free here: http://ahkscript.org/download/

You literally write code into a notepad document (or one of the free, community-developed text editors), and save it as *.ahk to make a script file.

There are commands such as:

```
Run, Chrome.exe
WinWait, New Tab - Google Chrome
WinActivate, New Tab - Google Chrome
Send, {F6}www.example.com{Enter}
Sleep, 1000
MsgBox, Action complete.
Return
```

That *script* will

- Start Chrome
- Wait until a window named "New Tab - Google Chrome" exists
- Activate the window
- Send the keystrokes [F6] www.example.com [Enter]
- Stop for 1 second
- Show a message box with "Action complete."

There is even GUI script for creating forms with buttons and controls. Here is a code snippet from a form application I was working on a while back:

```
Gui, Add, Button, x16 y15 w108, Activate Window 1
Gui, Add, Button, x16 y44 w108, Activate Window 2
Gui, Add, Button, x16 y73 w108, Activate Window 3
Gui, Add, Button, c000000 x24 y469 w100, Reset
Gui, Add, Button, x24 y498 w100 default, Run
Gui, Color, 404040, 000000
Gui, Show, Center w645, Repeat Keystrokes
return

buttonActivateWindow1:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
GuiControl,, Keystrokes, %Keystrokes%<window>%Activate1WindowText%</window>
GuiControl, Focus, Keystrokes
Send, ^a{End}
return

buttonActivateWindow2:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
GuiControl,, Keystrokes, %Keystrokes%<window>%Activate2WindowText%</window>
GuiControl, Focus, Keystrokes
Send, ^a{End}
return

buttonActivateWindow3:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
GuiControl,, Keystrokes, %Keystrokes%<window>%Activate3WindowText%</window>
GuiControl, Focus, Keystrokes
Send, ^a{End}
return
```

And yes, you can handle events when text is in a particular window, or even when a certain image is on a window.

Here is an example of a copy and paste script I wrote, which allows you to copy multiple items, then paste them one by one:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#CommentFlag //
#Persistent

// '#SingleInstance Force' only allows one instance of this script
// to run at a time.
// '#CommentFlag //' changes the scripts comment delimiter. I like
// "//" for comments.
// '#Persistent' kees the script running for objects like a timer.


// Create new array as an object.
ParseBoard := Object()

// Define new hotkey event for Ctrl+C
// It overrides the system's event for Ctrl+C
$^c::
     KeyWait, c

// Clear the clipboard.
clipboard =

// Copy the selected text.
Send, ^c
ClipWait

// Add text to array.
ParseBoard.Push(clipboard)

// Store the number of items currently in the array, as 'ParseCount'.
ParseCount := ParseBoard.MaxIndex()

// Display number of items copied on a tooltip for 2.5 seconds.
ToolTip, %ParseCount%
SetTimer, RemoveTT, 2500
Return

Return


// Define new hotkey event: Ctrl+V
^v::

// Stop if the shift key is down.
if (GetKeyState("Shift", "P") = 1)
     Return
KeyWait, v

// Return oldest string in array, and send keystrokes.
CurrentString := ParseBoard.RemoveAt(1)
SendInput, %CurrentString%

// Update the total items in array, within variable 'ParseCount'.
ParseCount := ParseBoard.MaxIndex()

// Display tooltip of remaining items for 2.5 seconds
ToolTip, %ParseCount%
SetTimer, RemoveTT, 2500

// Stop script.
Return


// The go-to tag for the timers. Removes tooltip from the screen.
RemoveTT:
     SetTimer, RemoveTT, Off
     ToolTip
     Return


// New hotkey event: Ctrl+Shift+V
$^+v::
KeyWait, v

// Send the last pasted item, instead of the next.
SendInput, %CurrentString%

// Stop script.
return


// Allow user to kill the entire script with the Escape key.
^Esc::ExitApp
```

And the script which can do just what you are wanting to do is posted here: http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm

It searches the screen for an image, and allows you to to handle accordingly.

In your case, you can take a snapshot of the messagebox, save it, reference its path, and use if (...)... else...

It also comes with a compiler, so you can use it on other computers as an *.exe file.